# How to insert dash symbols into character variables (SAS)?

Tags: string, replace, sas

So in SAS I have a length 10 character-type variable `fooword`. What I want to accomplish is that when a custom format is applied

```
format fooword $fooformat.;
```

dash symbols are displayed after every two symbols (from right to left). In other words **BERRY** would look like **B-ER-RY** and **STRAWBERRY** would look like **ST-RA-WB-ER-RY**.

Surely I can create a new longer variable and add dashes by using a bunch of `substr()` but that looks like a terrible solution in my eyes.

So...

```
proc format;
    value $fooformat
    ???
    ;
run;
```

Comment: I would be - pleasantly - surprised if that is possible.  Custom formats are a translation to an static value (static as-in: pre-defined). If you want your functionality available for flexible use, it is probably better to consider writing your custom function or a small macro. If you only need it once, just write it as (part of) a data step.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a format, but I bet you can with a regular expression. Find the right regex to insert a dash after each two-character sequence, then user the PRXCHANGE function in SAS.  sorry I don't know regex myself, but I bet if you revised this question and add the "regex" tag, you'd get lots of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with a format, sadly.  Possible with a FCMP function or a regex.  A regex that might work would be like so:

```
data test;
length origtext fintext $50;
input origtext $;
fintext=prxchange('s/([a-z]{2})(?=[a-z])/$1-/io',-1,origtext);
put origtext= fintext=;
datalines;
BLACKHOLES
GRAVITYWELL
DOREMIFASOLATI
;;;;
run;
```

Looks for 2 alpha characters, then a positive lookahead for another alpha character (so it doesn't throw one onto the end), then replaces with same plus a dash.  You could make a FCMP function that either did this or simply iterated through the string placing dashes throughout. That would be more similar to the format in usage, if not in actual details.